# Unable to upload a Django project to Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am trying to test the codes of the [project](http://code.google.com/p/cnprog/).

I run the following code

```
$appcfg.py update masicode/
```

I get the following error

```
Scanning files on local disk.
Initiating update.
2009-04-06 21:58:42,401 ERROR appcfg.py:1235 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Coding/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1213, in DoUpload
    missing_files = self.Begin()
  File "/Applications/Coding/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1009, in Begin
    version=self.version, payload=self.config.ToYAML())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 303, in Send
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 380, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 491, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 418, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 353, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 499, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Error 403: --- begin server output ---
You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u'so').
--- end server output ---
```

The contents of masicode

```
$ls masicode/
app.yaml   index.yaml main.py
```

**How can you upload Django project successfully to Google App Engine?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like login/permissions problem.

> HTTP Error 403: Forbidden 
>   You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u'so').

Your appID should be same as the one you have registered in Google App Engine. Your mail and password same as credentials that you've used to register it. 
Is http://so.appspot.com/ yours?

Further reading on deploying Django on App Engine:

- Official Google's article [Django on App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html)
- Thomas Brox Røst ["Django on Google App Engine in 13 simple steps"](http://thomas.broxrost.com/2008/04/08/django-on-google-app-engine/)

Comment: Thank you! I changed my appID. I get a helloworld -page after uploading the folder "so" of the project (I cannot find the folder anymore from their svn). Which folder should I upload to test the code at http://cnprog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you develop it specifically for App Engine using a modified Django library such as http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/? App Engine is a different environment than your standard Python install and apps that were not developed for it will not work (and possibly deploy) correctly.

Does the app run correctly in the App Engine development environment?